# RxJs: conditional switchMap if emitted value is empty

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this code :

```
const id = 1; // id = 2

of([{id: 1, name: 'abc'}]).pipe(
            map(items => items.find(item => item.id === id)),
            switchMap(item => item ? of(item) : this.makeHttpRequest(id))
        );

makeHttpRequest(id: number): Observable<IdNamePair>{}
```

in short,

- if object with specific id is found in array, return observable
  of({id: 1, name: 'abc'})
- if object not found in array, return observable returned by
  this.makeHttpRequest(id) method

I want to eliminate the of(item) operator.

This code works but is there a way without creating a new observable and reusing the one created by "map()" ?

edit:

```
export class MyService {
    private _list = new BehaviorSubject([{id: 1, name: 'abc'}]);
    list = this._list.asObservable();

    findOne(id: number) {
        this.list.pipe(
                    map(items => items.find(item => item.id === id)),
                    switchMap(item => item ? of(item) : this.makeHttpRequest(id))
                );
    }
}
```

in Angular component :

```
export class MyComponent {

    item$: Observable<IdNamePair>;

    constructor(private service: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
            this.item$ = this.service.findOne(1); // or (2), id comes from router
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think there is. The function passed in `switchMap` as parameter **has to return an Observable**. In the case of `item` null, this is performed by `this.makeHttpRequest(id)`. In the other case you have to find a way to create an Observable, and `of` seems the most natural way.

Comment: you want to implement a sort of cache if I understand. So if you already have the element you don't fetch it. In this case create your observable from the 'cahce' maybe is not the best aproach. you'r event should be the id you pass not the list you try to filter. If I'm in the right drection I can help you with an implementation

Comment: You have two `of()`s so which one you want to get rid of?

Comment: You could do it without `of`. For example `from` coupled with `filter`, but you would wait for completion, for example using `toArray`. The point is, the solution would be more complicated and not necessarily elegant.

Comment: @martin, the second "of()" inside the switchMap operator. I'm looking for something like an "else()" operator. There's an "iif()" operator, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @rick, yes exactly, it's meant to query the cache. I've edited the post and added more code, in hope it makes more sense now. If it's in the cache, the "findOne" method should return an observable of the item, if not it should return an http request as observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

```
const id = 1; // id = 2

const [hasItem, noItem] = of([{id: 1, name: 'abc'}]).pipe(
            map(items => items.find(item => item.id === id)),
            partition(Boolean)
        );

const res = merge(hasItem, noItem.pipe(switchMapTo(this.makeHttpRequest(id))
```